# C# read a class tree path in a string and access a value given an instance of that class

Tags: c#, reflection

In C#, is it possible to read a class tree path in a string and access programmatically a value, given an instance of that class ?

For example:

```
public class LogGeometricModel
{
  public double SmallEndDiameter { get; set; }
  public double LargeEndDiameter { get; set; }

public class Log
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public LogGeometricModel GeometricModel { get; set; }
}

public class Solution
{
  public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
  public double Price { get; set; }
  public Log RotatedLog { get; set; }
}
```

The strings could be something like this (a path in the class tree):

**SmallEndDiameter** = "Solution/RotatedLog/GeometricModel/SmallEndDiameter"

**LargeEndDiameter** = "Solution/RotatedLog/GeometricModel/LargeEndDiameter"

**Price** = "Solution/Price"

**Id** = "Solution/Log/Id"

By reading those strings, I would like to access the actual values of SmallEndDiameter, LargeEndDiameter, Price and Id.

Comment: You can trivially write a generic recursive method (or non-generic iterative, like Steve's example) to do that using reflection. Ordinarily, in a .NET environment we'd use dots as separators rather than slashes. I'm sure I've seen examples of this on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely possible yes.

```
public static object GetValue(object instance, string path)
{
    object currentObject = instance;
    foreach (string propertyName in path.Split('/'))
    {
        currentObject = currentObject
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty(propertyName)
            .GetValue(currentObject, null);
    }
    return currentObject;
}
```

You don't need to include 'Solution' in the string. This obviously lacks error handling, which if you are parsing a string like this, you will want.